# DB2 SQL: How do I add columns from the 'WHERE EXISTS' table to the select statement

Tags: sql, db2, where-clause, exists

Letsay I have this query:

```
select A.ID_NUM,A.EFF_DT,B.STRT_DT,B.END_DT
FROM MEMBERSHIP A
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM PLAN B
WHERE A.ID = B.ID)
```

How do I add columns from the PLAN table (B.STRT_DT,B.END_DT) to the select statement?
I get the error: B.STRT_DT is not valid in the context where it is used SQLCODE = 206

Answer (score 2):

You use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT M.ID_NUM, M.EFF_DT, P.STRT_DT, P.END_DT
FROM MEMBERSHIP M JOIN
     PLAN P
     ON M.ID = P.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

A join would be the simplest way, although if your PLAN table is not unique on it's ID column, you would need to add a DISTINCT, either before (or after) the join.

```
SELECT A.ID_NUM,A.EFF_DT,B.STRT_DT,B.END_DT
FROM MEMBERSHIP A
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM PLAN) B 
ON ( A.ID = B.ID )
```